# String variable in nested for loop not getting modified

Tags: java, arrays, split, nested-loops

Before I get into the issue, let me describe the problem that the code is supposed to be solving.

The code is supposed to take in input from a file in the following syntax:

```
 1,2,3,4;5
```

The code is supposed to take the integer that is after the semicolon and assign it to a variable, which it does. Then the code is supposed to take the values that are before the semicolon and find and return all two pairs of integers that add up to the value after the semicolon.

**Example:** if the input is

```
1,2,3,4;5
```

then the output should be

```
1,4;3,2
```

The problem I have is that my `String result` is not being edited by the nested `for` loops within the code. I get no compile time or runtime errors. It just does not edit the `String result` and I can't figure out why. Could you guys take a look?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class NumberPairs2 {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException { 
        File file = new File("C:/Users/James/Desktop/txt.txt"); // Takes in a file as input
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            String result = ""; // creates an empty string
            line = line.trim(); // set the file contents equal to null
            if (line.length() != 0){
                int sumTest = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(line.indexOf(";") + 1));
                String[] intArray = line.split(";");
                String[] intArray2 = intArray[0].split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i < intArray2.length - 1; i++){
                    for(int j = i + 1; i < intArray2.length; i++){
                        if (intArray2[i] != "," && intArray2[j] != "," && Integer.parseInt(intArray2[i]) + Integer.parseInt(intArray2[j]) == sumTest){
                            result += intArray[i] + ", " + intArray[j] + ";";
                            System.out.println(result);
                        }
                    }
                }


                //int compare = ()

            }
            else {
                result = null;
                System.out.println(result);
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your question. I tried to break up the large paragraph into smaller chunks, with proper code formatting; I've removed a lot of "so"s and fixed the code indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `intArray2[i]` & `intArray2[j]` when adding to `result` instead of `intArray[i]` & `intArray[j]`. Your code is currently getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` while trying to use `intArray2` indices in `intArray`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < intArray2.length - 1; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < intArray2.length; j++){
        if (Integer.parseInt(intArray2[i]) + Integer.parseInt(intArray2[j]) == sumTest){ 
            result += intArray2[i] + ", " + intArray2[j] + ";";
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

one option to remove the last semicolon would be to append to result as follows

```
//if not 1st pair, add semicolon
if(!result.equals("")){
    result += "; ";
}
result += intArray2[i] + ", " + intArray2[j];
```

Comment: I did your changes, and the incrementing j and i comparisons was a mistake i didnt mean to put that there but I fixed everything you said and result still isnt being edited

Comment: Hmm... have you tried `result = result + ...;`? I'm pretty sure `+=` should work, but I don't see anything else that looks wrong.

Comment: That doesnt work either. This litteraly makes no sense

Comment: I'd suggest printing out the values in the arrays and sumTest to make sure they are added correctly.

Comment: I have already printed out each array and the sumTest int to see if they are correctly being added adn modifed and they are

Comment: After running the code through Eclipse I spotted the problem. Hard to believe it was so easy to overlook actually! You're adding `intArray[i]` and `intArray[j]` instead of `intArray2[i]` and `intArray2[j]`. Since `intArray` has a length of 2, you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because `i` and `j` are based on `intArray2` indices. Updated my answer accordingly!

Comment: Ok it is working in CodeEval but not my editor for some reason...must be a problem on ym side. Ok im trying to figure out how i can keep the semicolon in between numbers but discard the one at the very end. I tried System.out.println(result.substring(0, result.length()-1))); but i got a index out of bounds exception. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
for (int i = 0; i < intArray2.length - 1; i++){
      for(int j = i + 1; j < intArray2.length; j++){
         if (Integer.parseInt(intArray2[i]) + Integer.parseInt(intArray2[j]) == sumTest){
           result += intArray2[i] + ", " + intArray2[j] + ";";
           }
      }
 }
 System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Ok it is working in CodeEval but not my editor for some reason...must be a problem on ym side. Ok im trying to figure out how i can keep the semicolon in between numbers but discard the one at the very end. I tried System.out.println(result.substring(0, result.length()-1))); but i got a index out of bounds exception. Any ideas?

Comment: result = result.replaceAll("\\;$","");